# Add Basic WWW-Authenticate to Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

[WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) is a way to add basic authentication to a web page, which requires a user to enter name and password before they can view content of the page. How can I add Basic WWW-Authenticate to a public Visualforce page?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in SF is behind a login screen so trying to create your own for a VF page is kind of silly.

- If you need users outside your org to access content, use a
  community. Communities allow for password authentication.
- If you want Salesforce to act as a service provider while an external
  service handles authentication, use SSO
- If you want to create a webservice that is capable of authenticating
  into SF, use OAuth

If you want to create a VF page that is password protected as a measure of avoiding purchasing licenses, we won't help you.

### WWW-Authenticate

The documentation you yourself linked explains that the WWW-Authenticate header is a **response header** that is sent along side a 401 error. This means the server sends it to the client, not the other way around. The header exists primarily so that the server can tell the client what method they should use to try to login to your server. **This DOES NOT allow users to provide a password so they can access the page**.

### Update

Here are some resources for working with external apis:

- [Rest API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm)
- [Webservices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest.htm)
- [Soap API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/)

### Custom APIs

As mentioned above everything in SFDC is behind a password screen, including external apis. There is no reason to attempt to manually secure apis. If you attempt to access an API without permission SFDC should automatically send out an error in the form of a WWW-Authenticate header.

If you **really** wanted to you could create a community and expose your API publicly to allow apis to access your org without a password (this is a completely different topic).

In order to manually control the WWW-Authenticate header, you would have to create an API expose it publicly and then, validate the password manually and then manually build and return the WWW-Authenticate header. This is a ton of unnecessary work. **Don't do it**.

Comment: Okay, is it possible to add basic authentication using WWW-Authenticate to a public VF page?

Comment: No, it's not possible to add that to any web page at all ever. That's not how that works. You are grievously misunderstanding the resource you are reading.

Comment: .htaccess, right?

Comment: No, that's not what a .htaccess does. .htaccess is also not relevant at all for SFDC or visualforce pages.

Comment: Well, I need it for an api integration. I was hoping Salesforce could do it. Looks like I will need to build an external application.

Comment: API integration is not what your question implies you're trying to do. You need to research rest services and or the SOAP Api as well as authentication for these.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some resources you can look over for building SFDC integrations.

Comment: Hey Tyler, this might be a good opportunity to step back and ask a slightly broader (but specific, with details) question about your proposed architecture and try to get some more clarity about what will and won't work for you.